# How to generate a random number that is evenly divisible by another randomly generated number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, random

I'm working on a simple math flashcards app using JavaScript and jQuery. The available operations are addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, each of which have functions that use `generateTop()` and `generateBottom()` to assign values to HTML elements.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use my division problem function to generate random numbers so that the`topNumber` is evenly divisible by the `bottomNumber`. I'm using the following code to generate random numbers for each problem:

```
let topNumber = 0;
let bottomNumber = 0;

function generateTop(max, min){
  topNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  return topNumber;
};

function generateBottom(max, min){
  bottomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  return bottomNumber;
};
```

Here is my current division problem generator:

```
function division(){
  problemTop.html(generateTop(1, 144));
  problemBottom.html(generateBottom(1, topNumber));
  opSym.html("÷");
}
```

I can adjust the max and min to get a positive integer for addition, subtraction, and multiplication problems but am stuck on how to ensure that I get a positive integer for division problems. I've tried messing with some different loop ideas but haven't gotten anything to work. I want to keep min at 1 and max at 144.

I've checked SO for solutions but can only find how to generate random numbers divisible by one other explicit, hard-coded number. How can I adjust my division function so that the `topNumber` can be divided evenly by the `bottomNumber`?

Comment: By definition, any number that is evenly divisible by `bottomNumber` must be a multiple of `bottomNumber`. Therefore you can just do `topNumber = topNumber*bottomNumber`. I leave the issue of min and max for you to solve

Comment: Think about it. You can easily generate a single random number, right? If the 2nd number must be evenly divisible by the first, that means the 2nd must be a multiple of the first. Therefore, just multiply your first number by 1, 2, 3...12 and then take one of those at random as your 2nd number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a single if statement to make your function recursive:

```
function generateBottom(max, min) {
    bottomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    if (topNumber % bottomNumber) {
        generateBottom(max, min);
    }
    return bottomNumber;
}
```

What this does is it divides `topNumber` and checks if a remainder exists. If there is a remainder, it means the two do not divide, so it is recalculated. Otherwise, it returns `bottomNumber` as per usual.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `denomenator` parameter to your `generateTop` function, and pass in the randomly generated "bottom" (denominator) number returned from `generateBottom`. Multiply the new random number created in `generateTop` by the denominator, and return that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```js
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) 
var b = a * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) 
var c = b/a;

document.write(b + " is divisible by " + a + " ( *" + c + ")" )
```

**In a * b, b is always divisible by a.**

```js
let topNumber = 0;
let bottomNumber = 0;

function generateTop(max, min, a){
  
  topNumber = a * Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  return topNumber + " is divisible by " + a + " ( *" + topNumber/a + ")";
  
};

function generateBottom(max, min){
  
  bottomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  return bottomNumber;
  
};

document.write(generateTop(10, 1, generateBottom(10, 1)))
```